# How to find the most repeating row?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax, filtering, row

Consider the following table:

```
tab={{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,1}}
```

Could you please tell me whether there is a command which returns the row which is repeated the most times?

Say, for the given example, it is `{1,0,0,1}`, which is repeated 3 times.

The problem is that first, I have to select unique rows, and second the counting should be made. In my real case, there is a table with 18 columns and $10^4$ rows, so the algorithm is sensitive to performance.

Comment: `Counts[tab]` meet you?

Comment: Tally[l tab ][[1, 1]]

Comment: `Commonest @ tab`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tab = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
   0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}

Commonest[tab]
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 1}}

```
{#, Count[tab, First@#]} &@Commonest[tab]
```

> {{{1, 0, 0, 1}}, 3}

Answer (score 7):

```
First @ Keys @ ReverseSort @ Counts[tab]
```

{1, 0, 0, 1}

Or

```
First @ Normal @ ReverseSort @ Counts[tab]
```

{1, 0, 0, 1} -> 3

**Timings**

Timings are more or less equal:

```
ran = RandomInteger[1, {10^6, 4}];

First @ Keys @ Counts[ran]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

0.293924

```
Tally[ran][[1, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

0.299086

```
Commonest[ran]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

0.297343

```
MaximalBy[PositionIndex[ran], Length] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

0.258426

**Edit**

Since the question is also about performance:

With `ParallelTable` and running on 4 kernels you get a significant speed gain with:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
ran = RandomInteger[1, {10^6, 4}];

(a = ReverseSort @ Counts[ran]); // RepeatedTiming // First
```

0.299939

```
(b = ReverseSort @ Merge[ParallelTable[
    Counts[Partition[ran, Length[ran]/4][[i]]], {i, 4}], Total]); // RepeatedTiming // First
```

0.0864523

```
a == b
```

True

It should also be noted that `Counts` and `Tally` must `ReverseSort` the result. `Commonest` and `MaximalBy` (like their names suggest) deliver an already sorted result. I added `ReverseSort` to my above answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
MaximalBy[PositionIndex[tab],Length]

(* <|{1, 0, 0, 1} -> {1, 2, 4}|> *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for variety and to show comparison.[`MaximalBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy.html) as per other users. I have voted for other answers.

```
f1[u_] := MaximalBy[Tally[u], Last]
f2[u_] := 
 MaximalBy[Reap[Map[Sow[1, {#}] &]@u, _, {#1, Total@#2} &][[2]], 
  Last]
f3[u_] := MaximalBy[{#[[1]], Length@#} & /@ Split[Sort[u]], Last]
f4[u_] := MaximalBy[KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[u, # &, Length]], Last]
```

Testing:

```
test = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {1000, 18}];
at[u_] := AbsoluteTiming[u[test]]
Grid[{#, at@#} & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another method using `GroupBy` and `Repeated`:

```
MaximalBy[{#[[1]][[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ Normal[GroupBy[tab, Repeated, Length]], Last]

(*{1, 0, 0, 1}*)
```

Or using `GatherBy`and `SortBy`:

```
First@*Last@SortBy[GatherBy[tab, Repeated], Length]

 (*{1, 0, 0, 1}*)
```